# Change owner and permissions of every dataset created by my job

Tags: permissions, sas, dataset, pipe, chown

I need to change the owner and permissions of every dataset that my job generates. I need to include that in my post processing process. I can use the chown command using X or pipe in my SAS code to change the permissions of the latest created dataset. Suggest ways to get a list of all the permanent datasets created in the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no SAS on/off option 'journaling' feature that automatically identifies the runner/job that created the data sets.  SAS installed in big iron (mainframe) operating systems, or maybe OpenVMS, might have it done automatically by the OS.

Do you know the `<path>` of the libnames used when creating the new data sets ?

One approach relies on `find` options `-newer`

> **-newer file**
>                 File  was  modified  more recently than file.  If file is a symbolic link and the -H option or the -L option is in effect, the modification time of the file it points to is always used.

So you want to

- start of job - create a marker file
- end of job - find the files newer than the marker file and execute the `chown` command on them

Eaxmple:

```
libname joblib '~/myjobs/sasdata';

* create marker file;
%sysexec touch /tmp/job-start.tag

* sas code;

* chown and chmod each newer file;
%sysexec find ~/myjobs/sasdata -type f -newer /tmp/job-start.tag -exec chmod 755 {} \%str(;);
%sysexec find ~/myjobs/sasdata -type f -newer /tmp/job-start.tag -exec chown newower {} \%str(;);
```

**Alternate ways to tag SAS data sets from within the job**

The idea is to separate, tag or mark data sets in a way that discriminates them from other jobs

Way 1. **Jobs create independent sets of data sets:**

Create a new job-unique folder for each run:

- Use a common libref, such as `JOB`, in the source code but have it point to the new folder
- Run the job, creating new data sets.
- Perform the post-job tweaks
- Move the new data sets to `PERM`, their permanent storage location

Way 2. **Job source is dependent on data sets in `PERM` and can't be changed**:

Use library path concatenation:

- Change libname prior to job launch
  `libname PERM ("<path-to-new-job-unique-folder">, "<path to actual PERM>")`;
- New data sets will be created in the first path of the concatenation.
- Post-job process data sets as discussed earlier

Way 3. **Use a macro variable to label each data set in the job**

- Change job code from
  `DATA xyz; …`
  to
  `%let JOB_TIMESTAMP=%sysfunc(datetime());     %* this is a job 'tag' for job-unique identification;
  %let JOB_LABEL=(label="JOBID:&JOB_LABEL");
  DATA xyz &JOB_LABEL; …`
- Post job, use `PROC CONTENTS` or SQL `DICTIONARY.TABLES` to determine data sets having &JOB_TIMESTAMP in their label.

Way 4. **Jobs run on SAS server, labels can't be altered**

- Update JOB source code so that each data set the job creates gets a corresponding metadata note created that contains the &JOB_TIMESTAMP.
- Post job, scan the metadata notes for the &JOB_TIMESTAMP and adjust the ones that match.

Way 5. **Create AUDIT data set for each data set created by the job**

- Search help for "Understanding an Audit Trail"
- Post job search the audit table for the job tag

Other ways

- Create your own tracking table for a job
- JOB source must be altered and macros can help enforce consistency through out:

  `%macro jobtracker(data=, id=);
    … insert into perm.jobtracker values ("&data", "&id") …
  %mend;
  …
  %jobtracker(data=analysis1, id=&JOB_TIMESTAMP)  %* manually track each table;
  data analysis1;
    …`
- Post job, process datasets per `PERM.JOBTRACKER` and `&JOB_TIMESTAMP`.

If the above don't work for you, add more information to the question:

- How are the jobs launched?
- How close together, timewise, are the starts?
- How many jobs are running in parallel?
- Can jobs collide in the creation of or dependency on new data sets?
- Do you have complete control over the source code and data set options applied?

Comment: There would be multiple jobs running parallely creating multiple datasets in the library, I just wish to update the dataset pertaining to the current job. if I'm understanding correctly, your code will update all the datasets in the library which are created after the marker file creation, which I do not want.

Comment: Thanks Richard I'll try using the third method to append each dataset with a timestamp and then remove that later on.

Answer (score 0):

When you said "permanent datasets", you must mean those data sets were stored in one or several place. Why not just use `filename test pipe "dir /b/s X:\xxxxxx\*.sas7dbat"` to get the list?